# How many times can I search a day? Google Site Search restriction?

Tags: webclient, google-search-api

I am developing a software that can search from Google programatically.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("http://www.google.com/search?hl=ja&num=100&q=");
sb.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kensakuword).ToString());
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
return webClient.DownloadString(sb.ToString());
```

I works fine if used this code several times, but found that if I tried to retrieve more than around 60 or 70 words, it fails with exception as follows.

```
{System.Net.WebException: remote server returned an error (503) 
System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
```

Is there any solution?
Is it a restriction of Google Site Search?
It seems that a program can get one hundred results from Google a day.

Comment: I found that I can call webclient to search Google 50 times at once. I am not going to cheat search engine, but how does it distinguish the difference between program search and manual search. I am putting user agent in my program...

Answer (score 1):

After that 60-70 search mark Google inserts a Captcha key.  You either need to slow down your scraping or hire a service that will type in Captcha codes.

This is reset hourly.  I think the threshold is about 200 searches per hour.

Comment: I understand Google behaves like this, but is it way to show Captcha screen/Captcha code programatically? Because I am developing a standalone software.